# asp.net cascading dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have the following model :

Trucktype

- ID
- Description
- List of ModelCodes

ModelCodes

- Id
- Code

Now I want to create a page which has two dropdowns one for the TruckType and one for the ModelCode so that I can display the trucks that correspond to the selection.

I can fill the first one, but how do I fill the second dropdown once you selected a value in the first dropdown?

Comment: You'll need some client side code to perform this. You know JavaScript? You know how to detect when a value is changed, and then how to adjust the values in another dropdown? What have you tried? What went wrong with your attempt? Can you provide us a [MCVE]?

Comment: I was looking at the change-event using javascript, but I wasn't able to get the value from the selectedTruckTypes modelcodes.

Comment: Well it's hard to show us what went wrong if you don't provide us with a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Consider `dropdownlist1` the one which will filter the results in `dropdownlist2` and adapt to your db schema and context, obviously.

```
$("#dropdownlist1_ID").change(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GetValuesForDropdownlist2',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: $("#dropdownlist1_ID").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#dropdownlist2_ID").append('<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            console.log('Failed to retrieve data. Exception: ' + ex);
        }
    });
});
```

In the controller something like:

```
public JsonResult GetValuesForDropdownlist2(int id)
{
    var selected = db.dropdownlist1_Table.Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    return Json(new SelectList(db.dropdownlist2_Table.Where(t => (t.Column_To_Filter == selected.Id)), "Column_ID", "Column_Description"));
}
```